# Verb or Prepositional Phrase

Tags: complementation

Actually, I have a theoritical part to cover with details about Verb, Noun, Prepositional and Adjective Phrases regarding Complements of Adjectives.

I have done 80% of my work but still got stuck with this example and one more that I have encountered yesterday thanks for the support of members of this forum.

The first example was taken from [this page](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/phil/english/sections/linguist/real/independent/eafrica/Diss_Diana/dissch4-1.htm).

> [4.1.5.22] It was most spontaneous *for me to write in English*.

In my opinion, I will put the italic phrase into **Verb Phrase** as there is a to-Infinitive clause here. However, how about *for me*? Maybe one will put them into **Prepositional Phrase** because of *for*?

My second question is which phrase should you put *making cakes* into? The example is: I am *busy making cakes*. I am doing research about **Complements of Adjectives** but I haven't met any example like this, check [this page](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/what-is-an-adjective-complement.html) or [that one](http://www.cambridge.org/grammarandbeyond/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/List-of-Adjectives-+-Complemements_JM_JB.pdf). But it is true that *making cakes* here is a complement and I cannot ignore it.

Once again, I ask two questions at the same time. Sorry about this.

Comment: The construction *for + noun/pronoun + infinitive* is used when the infinite needs its own subject. It can be phrased with a clause: *it was most spontaneous that I write in English.*

Comment: Some pointers: "*to*-infinitivals with and without a subject", "gerund-participials" (also known as "*-ing* participle clauses", or "present participles").

Answer (score 1):

1. The preposition *for* and *of* have a special function in English. It can indicate a subject of the action indicated by a *to infinitive* in a sentence which starts with *expletive it* (dummy it, dummy pronoun). For example:

> A: It is important to attend the seminar. (To attend the seminar is important.)
>
> B: For me or you?
>
> A: It is important **for you** to attend the seminar.

A's first sentence is ambiguous and doesn't indicate who should attend the seminar. A's second sentence is very clear and indicates who should.

*For you* in the above example is a *prepositional phrase* to indicate a subject of to infinitive.

Note: You should use *of* when you use adjectives (good, nice, brace, stupid, kind, clever, etc.) that describe human nature, e.g., "It was nice **of** you to to help me."

2. "making cakes" in the example is a [dangling participle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/dangling-participles) which is

> Participles of verbs are often used to introduce subordinate clauses,
>   which give extra information about the main part of a sentence (known
>   as the main clause). It’s important to use participles in subordinate
>   clauses correctly. The participle should always describe an action
>   performed by the subject of the main part of the sentence.

For example:

> A: I am busy.
>
> B: Doing what?
>
> A: I am busy *making cakes*.

As you can see, A's first sentence is not clear on why A is busy. But A's second sentence clearly states A is busy because A is making cakes. The dangling participle gives extra information about the subject's action or status.

I would not call it "complement of adjective" as it doesn't complement the adjective *busy*, but actually it complements the verb and its predicate *am busy*.

Some grammar books call it ["participle clause"](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/participle-clauses) and ["absolute construction (clause)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction). Whatever it is called, it is very important to note that the participle (making cakes) doesn't have a normal or usual syntactical relation with other words or sentence elements. It should always be a non-finite clause. You can't use make, to make, made, have made, had made, etc. in place of *making*.

Comment: I still wonder about _for you_ as a **Prepositional Phrase**. In the book **A Student's Introduction to English Grammar**, **Huddleston** and **Pullum** described (Page 220) _for them_ as in _We arranged for them to meet the manager_ as an **Intervening Noun Phrase**.

Comment: @HồQuangTrung Well, there is no universal term used in English grammar books. If you are interested in learning English, I advise you not to care so much about what they call it. Now, my question is why would it be a noun phrase? It is not a noun. It is intervening, but noun phrase??? It is not a noun. I wouldn't be able to understand why unless I read the chapter myself.

Comment: In this book and of the same page, they also used one example, _We counted on them to support us_, to figure out that in _on them_, _on_ is a **Preposition** for the **Verb** _to count_, therefore, _them_ is the **Complement** of _on_ while _on them_ is **Complement** of _counted_. They didn't mention which phrase _to support us_ belongs to.

Comment: I am busy writing the comments so I haven't added the book. The link is here: [link](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA215&lpg=PA215&dq=finite+complement+grammar&source=bl&ots=WQHGcYglsY&sig=CoCiZLTkpcRlqLFlvO_nXTW8Uns&hl=vi&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=finite%20complement%20grammar&f=false). Page 220 is shown as a preview.

Comment: To support us is a to-infinitive used adverbially. I don't understand what you are trying to say. Are you interested in "for X" or "on X" before to infinitive or to infinitive itself? I don't get it.

Comment: I need the concise terms or at least someone else used them once as I am doing writing a study. I have just finished my master course and have to publish some articles in a local newspaper. Complementation is a new topic to me so maybe I work with great care for what they are called. Sorry if this made you feel inconvenient. Some teachers of mine will check my article so I just want things to go in the right way.

Comment: You misunderstood what "NP" means in the book. Intervening NP is "them", not "for them".

Comment: Regarding your lastest comment, I am wondering when the non-finite clause contains both _for X_ and _to X_, which phrase should they belong to. In the first place, I have a table classifying them into 4 groups of phrases: **Noun Phrase**, **Verb Phrase**, **Adjective Phrase** and **Prepositional Phrase**. That's why I am concerned about which group they should be put in. Maybe should I put _for X to do X_ in both **Prepositional Phrase** and **Verb Phrase**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40365/discussion-between-rathony-and-h-quang-trung).

Comment: You can join the chat room by clicking on the above comment.

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot the word _preceded_ in the explanation of [i].

Comment: I am waiting in the chat room. Come.

Comment: Where is the chat room? I haven't seen any button?